# Github Action's Gradle complains memory settings not configured - I did

Tags: java, android, gradle, github-actions

I'm building & running my android unit tests on Github actions.

My gradle build logs says:

```
> Task :app:hiltJavaCompileDebug
The Daemon will expire after the build after running out of JVM Metaspace.
The project memory settings are likely not configured or are configured to an insufficient value.
The daemon will restart for the next build, which may increase subsequent build times.
These settings can be adjusted by setting 'org.gradle.jvmargs' in 'gradle.properties'.
The currently configured max heap space is '4 GiB' and the configured max metaspace is '256 MiB'.
For more information on how to set these values, visit the user guide at https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/build_environment.html#configuring_jvm_memory
To disable this warning, set 'org.gradle.daemon.performance.disable-logging=true'.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build after running out of JVM Metaspace
```

But that's not true - I've set the memory as below: (`gradle.properties`)

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

My Github Actions settings are as below:

```yaml
      - name: Run tests
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          cache-read-only: false
          arguments: "${{ env.command }}"
```

(where `env.command` is very long command with test names)

Anyone encountered similar problems?